# Burninate [data-processing]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [data-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-processing) tag currently has 613 questions over a wide range of topics, e.g.

- [How to smooth a curve in the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618804/how-to-smooth-a-curve-in-the-right-way)
- [Ways to read only select columns from a file into R? (A happy medium between `read.table` and `scan`?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193742/ways-to-read-only-select-columns-from-a-file-into-r-a-happy-medium-between-re)
- [Lua vs Embedded Lisp and potential other candidates. for set based data processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919763/lua-vs-embedded-lisp-and-potential-other-candidates-for-set-based-data-processi)
- [Best way to format large JSON file? (~30 mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875218/best-way-to-format-large-json-file-30-mb)
- [Algorithm for grouping anagram words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396005/algorithm-for-grouping-anagram-words)

The tag wiki says:

> Data Processing concerns the converting of raw data to machine-readable form and its subsequent processing (as storing, updating, rearranging, or printing out) by a computer.

This is a very broad definition, and would match much more than 613 questions (e.g., everything that queries databases would fit in that category).

I propose to remove this tag, and add better tags where appropriate. For the questions I have checked, it seemed to be completely superfluous and can be removed safely.

### Answers to the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it is very ambiguous, as the tag wiki shows.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes and no. While large parts of programming *are* about data processing, I cannot imagine an on-topic question about data processing *itself*, due to its broad definition.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, it does not give any indication what the post is about.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, as the tag wiki shows. It can be about converting files, filtering lists, printing documents, and so on.